# Generic dictionary in Swift

Tags: generics, swift3

I have several structs `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`, and I use the function below to read a plist into a [String : Foo] dictionary. And I have a method that creates a [String : Bar] dictionary, etc. This all works well.

```
func loadFoo() -> [String : Foo]? {
    guard
       let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "foo", ofType: "plist"),
       let plistDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String : AnyObject]
       else { return nil }

    var dict = [String : Foo]()

    for (key, f) in plistDict {
       if let info = f as? [String : AnyObject] {
           let foo = Foo(symbol: key, info: info)
           dict[key] = foo
        }
    }

    return dict
}
```

Of course, this screams "use generics", but I have not yet been able to get it to work. For instance, I replaced `Foo` with `<A>` or `A`, but get a bunch of compiler errors (I am away from my Mac right now, so cannot reproduce the errors here).

Any suggestions how to tackle this?

Comment: What is a `pList` variable?

Comment: A property list in Xcode; Oh, and a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a protocol that all common structs must conform to by implementing the init method `init(symbol:info:)`

  ```
  protocol Fooable {
    init(symbol: String, info: [String : AnyObject])
  }
  ```
- Make all your structs adopt that protocol

  ```
  struct Baz : Fooable { ...
  ```
- Now you can make the load method generic by constraining the type to `Fooable`

  ```
  func loadFoo<T:Fooable>() -> [String : T]? {
    guard
      let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "foo", ofType: "plist"),
      let plistDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String : AnyObject]
      else { return nil }

    var dict = [String : T]()

    for (key, f) in plistDict {
      if let info = f as? [String : AnyObject] {
        let foo = T(symbol: key, info: info)
        dict[key] = foo
      }
    }

    return dict
  }
  ```
- and call it with

  ```
  let bazObject : [String : Baz]? = loadFoo()
  ```

  This syntax to annotate the type passes `Baz` as the generic parameter.

Comment: So how do I call this? `myFooDict = loadFoo()` is not working (`unresolved identifier loadFoo`).

Comment: You need to pass the struct as generic parameter. Assuming you are using the `Baz` struct write `myFooDict = loadFoo<Baz>()`

Comment: Hmm, I still get the same error. Where does `loadFoo` reside? I tried it as an extension of `Loadable`, and get the above error. If I move it out of `Loadable`, the error is: `Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function` and `While parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the syntax is different in this case, I updated the answer

Comment: Ok, now I get this error: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` and `In call to function 'loadFoo'

Comment: The code is supposed to work. I tested it in a playground.

Comment: I'm afraid no, I tested in Swift 2. Indeed it doesn't work in Swift 3 but I have no idea (yet) why.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I should have made that clear, I will change the tag for the question and look for a solution.

Comment: Got it. When I tested it in Swift 3 I forgot to make the custom struct adopt `Fooable`  ->  `struct Baz : Fooable { ... `. The error message might be misleading.

Comment: Just for the record, that's the same reason why I got the error as well.